# Accessing a variable value outside of a while loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

How to read a value from inside while loop?

```
mm=""
while True:


    mm = "hello world"


print(mm) -  returns nothing
```

Is there any alternative is available to achieve this?

Comment: You have an infinite loop.

Comment: yeah need to do it this way only have some  dependencies to check

Comment: But you understand that you never reach the part with the `print`?

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: actually trying to read input box which has some different values if user select val first time i can save the variable value but if changes the val then the old value stays so ..

Comment: What is an `input box`?

Answer (score 1):

This will work once the while loop is break. You have to add break condition for while loop so after it breaks the variable value will be changed

check below code:

```
mm=""
while True:
    mm = "hello world"
    break

print(mm)
```

Comment: thanks amit it works only for first time my problem is i need to keep on listening to mm for change in value any way you can suggest it

Answer (score 0):

The code you have given is forming an infinite loop...you have to use `break` at the last of `while True` to make it work.

Code:

```
mm=""
while True:
    mm = "hello world"
    break
print(mm)
```

Additionally, if you are using the `while True:` loop inside a function...then it would be better to use the `return` function.

For example,

```
def def_name():
    mm=""
    while True:
        mm="hello world"
        return mm
    print(mm)
```

Happy to Help :)

Comment: thanks runs it works only for first time my problem is i need to keep on listening to mm for change in value any way you can suggest it